# How effectively detect surrogate pair in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, unicode

I need to detect surrogate pairs in hundreds of thousands of strings of various lengths.

I wonder what might be the fastest and most efficient way to do this.

```
    string srcString = " = ";
    var hasSurrogate = srcString.Any(c => '\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF');
```

`Any` works fine with its O(n) speed, but maybe there is a more efficient way to do this

Comment: I don't think you can get any kind of performance increase, except perhaps an *incredibly minor* one by not using `.Any` and just doing a straight `for` (not `foreach`) loop through the string. You could try doing it in parallel, but whether it's a performance increase or not would depend on the length of the strings and what you want to do with the result.

Comment: Well, to detect them, you'll need to analyse every character - I don't see a way to do this faster than O(n) - unless you analyse when the character is written and keep track of it in a lookup table.

Comment: To clarify: when I said in parallel, I mean over all the strings you have, not parallel over a single string.

Comment: Side note: `char.IsSurrogate(c)` or`char.IsHighSurrogate(c)` etc. are more readable than `'\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF'`

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Benchmark, then reason :) A for is much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing you can do is *measure*. Have a couple implementations and benchmark them. I've compared using `Any()` vs. `for`. A simple `for` cycle is **faster by a factor of 10**.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HasSurrogateAny | 8,095.7 ns | 160.38 ns | 230.01 ns |
| HasSurrogateFor | 765.8 ns | 14.19 ns | 13.27 ns |

I've used [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) with this simple code:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace PerfTests.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<SurrogateBenchmark>();
    }
}

public class SurrogateBenchmark
{
    private static string test = "".PadRight(1000) + " = ";

    [Benchmark]
    public bool HasSurrogateAny()
    {
        return test.Any(c => '\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF');
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public bool HasSurrogateFor()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = test[i];
            if ('\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF') return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that I've prepended 1000 spaces before the actual surrogate, so that the algorithms have some work to do and do not encounter a surrogate as the very first character in the string.

Environment: .NET 6.0.7, Intel Xeon Gold 16-core 2.4 GHz, WS2019 virtual machine

It turns out that a `foreach` offers essentially the same performance, as well as a more readable version which uses `Char.IsSurrogate()`:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HasSurrogateAny | 8,630.1 ns | 134.03 ns | 125.37 ns |
| HasSurrogateForEach | 770.1 ns | 10.31 ns | 9.14 ns |
| HasSurrogateForReadable | 796.0 ns | 13.41 ns | 12.54 ns |
| HasSurrogateFor | 773.2 ns | 11.46 ns | 10.72 ns |

And, finally, in my setup a version utilizing a `for` over a `Span<char>` is actually a bit *slower*:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HasSurrogateFor | 764.1 ns | 12.99 ns | 11.52 ns |
| HasSurrogateForSpan | 803.7 ns | 15.95 ns | 21.30 ns |

Code for the remaining three tests:

```
[Benchmark]
public bool HasSurrogateForEach()
{
    foreach (char c in test)
    {
        if ('\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF') return true;
    }
    return false;
}

[Benchmark]
public bool HasSurrogateForReadable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = test[i];
        if (Char.IsSurrogate(c)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

[Benchmark]
public bool HasSurrogateForSpan()
{
    var s = test.AsSpan();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = test[i];
        if ('\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF') return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's a bigger amount of time saved than I honestly expected between Any and for. I guess I was wrong about the "incredibly minor" saving by switching to for.

Answer (score 6):

You can't beat the complexity of `O(N)` because you have to inspect every character. But you can speed things up considerably by using a loop and `Span<Char>` - and by "considerably" I mean more than 10 times faster.

The fastest method I could come up with is this:

```
static bool searchUsingSpanIsSurrogate(string s)
{
    var span = s.AsSpan();

    foreach (var c in span)
    {
        if (char.IsSurrogate(c))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Out of interest I tried a few different methods. Here's the benchmark:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace Demo;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<UnderTest>();
    }
}

public class UnderTest
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void SearchUsingLinq()
    {
        _ = searchUsingLinq(_haystack);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SearchUsingSpan()
    {
        _ = searchUsingSpan(_haystack);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SearchUsingLinqIsSurrogate()
    {
        _ = searchUsingLinqIsSurrogate(_haystack);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SearchUsingSpanIsSurrogate()
    {
        _ = searchUsingSpanIsSurrogate(_haystack);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SearchUsingIndexedIsSurrogate()
    {
        _ = searchUsingIndexedIsSurrogate(_haystack);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SearchUsingLoop()
    {
        _ = searchUsingLoop(_haystack);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void SearchUsingLoopIsSurrogate()
    {
        _ = searchUsingLoop(_haystack);
    }

    static bool searchUsingLinq(string s)
    {
        return s.Any(c => '\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF');
    }

    static bool searchUsingSpan(string s)
    {
        var span = s.AsSpan();

        foreach (var c in span)
        {
            if ('\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF')
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static bool searchUsingLinqIsSurrogate(string s)
    {
        return s.Any(char.IsSurrogate);
    }

    static bool searchUsingSpanIsSurrogate(string s)
    {
        var span = s.AsSpan();

        foreach (var c in span)
        {
            if (char.IsSurrogate(c))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static bool searchUsingIndexedIsSurrogate(string s)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (char.IsSurrogate(s, i))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static bool searchUsingLoop(string s)
    {
        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            if ('\uD800' <= c && c <= '\uDFFF')
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static bool searchUsingLoopIsSurrogate(string s)
    {
        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            if (char.IsSurrogate(c))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    readonly string _haystack = new string('X', 100_000);
}
```

And here's the results:

```
|                        Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |    Median |
|------------------------------ |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|
|               SearchUsingLinq | 626.05 us |  9.130 us |  8.094 us | 625.55 us |
|               SearchUsingSpan | 102.21 us |  1.851 us |  1.732 us | 101.94 us |
|    SearchUsingLinqIsSurrogate | 746.70 us | 17.373 us | 49.284 us | 735.55 us |
|    SearchUsingSpanIsSurrogate |  53.00 us |  1.260 us |  3.675 us |  51.85 us |
| SearchUsingIndexedIsSurrogate |  62.64 us |  2.638 us |  7.736 us |  58.60 us |
|               SearchUsingLoop |  64.02 us |  1.581 us |  4.537 us |  62.19 us |
|    SearchUsingLoopIsSurrogate |  62.79 us |  1.228 us |  3.103 us |  61.47 us |
```

It looks like it doesn't really matter too much which of the non-Linq approaches you use, since they are all quite close in performance. Just don't use Linq if you want maximum performance, since the overhead of using a delegate is quite high.